# precision issue in the case of left side zero of a number

Tags: php, precision

my function is as follows:

```
static function applyPrecision($vals) {
        $originalNumber = $vals['reading'];
        if (is_numeric($originalNumber)) {
            $precision = ($vals['precision'] != '' || $vals['precision'] != 0) ? $vals['precision'] : 4;
            $factor = pow(10, $precision);
            $multipliedNumber = $originalNumber * $factor;
            //$integerMultipliedNumber = floor($multipliedNumber);
            $var = explode(".", $multipliedNumber);
            $integerMultipliedNumber = $var[0];
            return $result = (float) ($integerMultipliedNumber / $factor);
        } else {
            return $originalNumber;
        }
    }
```

using this , we can apply precision for a number without rounding the value
for eg:- 45.12345678
         precision given is 3,then output is 45.123

but if a number like this, :45.1000000
and precision is 3
then output coming like 45.1 only, that zeros are getting skipped, is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Check [number_format()](https://php.net/number-format)

Comment: this is a float not a string, if you want it to keep the zeros then you need to convert it to a string and check for the number of digits post period (.) you want -subtracted from number you have and add that many zeros

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou  that function will round the given value, so cannot use that for my function

Comment: @Shardj yes its a floating point number

Comment: @sarin so you understand that 14.100 is the same thing as 14.1 then?

Comment: @Shardj yes, but is there any way to display that zeros too?

Comment: If that's what you want then this is a string manipulation question really, ill post an answer

Comment: Do you want to keep only the 3 first digits every time? But without rounding up? Then you can use `number_format(floor($number * 1000) / 1000,3)`

Comment: That's actually a pretty good answer

Comment: `echo number_format(floor((float)$number), $precision, '.', '');` works pretty well and removes the rounding problem.

Comment: @JayBlanchard This will make the number an int first cause `floor(3.456) = 3`, also the duplicate you posted will round up the value and to my undestanding OP doesn't want to round up the value

Answer (score 0):

If this is a question about floats, 14.1 is the same as 14.100. If this is a question about strings then you should instead just be using `substr()`. Answer for that below where `$number` is the number to cut and `$precision` is how many decimal places you want.

```
$number = (string) $number;
$temp = $precision <= 0 ? 0 : $precision+1;
return substr($number, 0, strrpos($number, '.') + $temp);
```

Comment: precision can be different based on settings, may be 3,2 ,1,5 etc

Comment: we can make a logical solutions, but if there any mathematical solution can be make?

Comment: It cannot be a mathematical solution @sarin, because you desire to print a string, not a number once you decide to print the additional zero's.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this code doesn't work either, it only renders 14.1

Comment: You're mistaken Jay, it works perfectly. Just pop it into https://www.runphponline.com/ and define number and precision before this

Comment: <?php
$number=10.10000000000;
$precision=4;
$number = (string) $number;
$temp = $precision <= 0 ? 0 : $precision+1;
echo substr($number, 0, strrpos($number, '.') + $temp);
?>
 this will also return 100.10000000  as 100.1

Comment: That's because you entered a float sarin, please refer back to the first thing I said about floats and strings

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the first 3 subdigits of the float without rounding up you have to use `float($number*1000/1000)` then you use that with `number_format(float($number*1000/1000),3)`

example

```
$var =0.35489;
$var2 = number_format(floor($var * 1000) / 1000,3);
echo $var2;
```

output

0.354

example2

```
$var =0.3000;
$var2 = number_format(floor($var * 1000) / 1000,3);
echo $var2;
```

output2

0.300

If your precision is variable then you will have to use `pow(10,$precision)`

Example3

```
$var =0.3000;
$precision =3;
$var2 = number_format(floor($var * pow(10,$precision)) / pow(10,$precision),3);
```

output3

0.300

Comment: if value is like 45.568888 ,number_format function will round it to 45.569

Comment: not if you use floor first, read my example carefully

Comment: @sarin Check my example [here](https://3v4l.org/n2hpn). Output is `45.568`